# How to create a link which points to an image

Tags: ajax

I have a link which is currently pointing to a .txt file in my project.  I need to have that link point to a .jpg instead.  Currently when I use a .jpg i get macros.

I simply need for the link to asynchronously pull file from images dir within the project.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>JavaScript Ajax Demo</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!--<link href="styles/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">-->
    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>


    <div class="container">

        <div id="index">
            <a href="words/a.txt">A</a>
            <a href="words/b.txt">B</a>
            <a href="words/c.txt">C</a>
        </div>

        <form>
            <input type="submit" />
        </form>

        <div id="output">
        </div>

    </div>

    <script>
        window.addEventListener("load", function () {
            var indx = g("index");
            indx.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
                getData(e.target.href);
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });


        var temp = document.createElement("img");

        temp.src = "linktoyourimage.jpg"





        function getData(url) {
            // 1 - new XMLHttpRequest
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); // readyState = 0
            // 2 - Open
            //url = "http://google.com";
            xhr.open("GET", url); // readyState = 1
            // 3 - Set onreadystatechange event handler
            xhr.onreadystatechange = gotData;
            // 4 - Send
            xhr.send(); //readyState = 2
        }




        function gotData() {
            // readyState = 3 -> Receiving Data
            // readyState = 4 -> Ready to process response data
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                var op = g("output");
                op.innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        }



        function g(id) {
            return document.getElementById(id);
        }



    </script>

    <!-- /.container -->
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>-->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just change the `href` to point to the JPG then?  Use an `img` as the link's content instead of text?  It's not really clear what the issue is.

Comment: Thanks.  I did that and I get macros.  I think it has something to do with the gotData() at the bottom.  The line - op.innerHTML = this.responseText; is not expecting an image.  I tried to use Blob() but I guess I did not implement it correctly.  I want the link to display an in=mage file within the project dir.

Comment: What does "got macros" mean?  What did you try and in what way did it not work?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not really clear, but I will try to be helpful and guess what you really want...

In case of image you don't need to go and fetch its content, but you can change `src` of your `img` element.

Try to use this:

```
function getData(url) {
    if(url.substr(-3) === "jpg" ) {
        //if this is a jpg file, just point your img container to that
        temp.src = url;         
    }
    else{
        //otherwise go out and get the txt file, later display it in some container
        // 1 - new XMLHttpRequest
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); // readyState = 0
        // 2 - Open
        //url = "http://google.com";
        xhr.open("GET", url); // readyState = 1
        // 3 - Set onreadystatechange event handler
        xhr.onreadystatechange = gotData;
        // 4 - Send
        xhr.send(); //readyState = 2
    }
}
```

Also, change some link to point to `jpg` image.

I haven't tested this code, just wrote to show you the concept. So bear with me if it fails.